# Why does html call it 'td' and not 'tc' for table cell?

Tags: html

I haven't browsed through the spec, though I doubt any info is in there. Does it stand for table data?

Comment: @Kyle - true, but I still ask questions that are known in the wild if they're not covered elsewhere on SO.  40 views in 5 minutes suggests that it's a fun question and worth being posted.  Plus iyerrag looks like a new user, so be a little welcoming.

Comment: And now it will take 2 seconds for google to find it here. That's rather the point of SO.

Comment: @mgb: I think you might have this backwards.  Google already has the wikipedia link and that's all it needs.  SO should answer stuff that's programming related -- where there's code involved -- not replicate trivia that's available everywhere.

Comment: @Kyle and others whose sensibilities I hurt - yes, I could have googled... I didn't...  I said why not ask on stackoverflow. Don't vote the question up or start squabbling, please.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You have two options for table cells: TD or TH.

TH = Table Header

TD = Table Data.

Both are table cells.

Comment: Here is a link to the HTML 4.01 Specification that defines them: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6 (and refers to TH and TD as 'header' and 'data' cells - for the benefit of iyerrag).

Comment: also TF for Table Footer

Comment: I upvoted the tf answer too quickly. Now it won't let me reverse it. But there is no tf tag. There is a tfoot tag, similar to a thead, but td is used inside it. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tfoot.asp

Answer (score 13):

short answer: yes.

Answer (score 4):

Table Data Cell: http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/tables/td.html

Answer (score 2):

from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html_table#Tables):

> ```
> <td>...</td>
> ```
>
> A `<table>` data cell.
>
> Proposed in the HTML 3.0 Drafts; Standardised in HTML 3.2; still current.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it stands for "table data cell"

http://www.december.com/html/4/element/td.html

Comment: "TD" cannot stand for "table data cell", that would likely be "TDC". It may mean "table data cell" but I think the OP was really asking to what the letter "D" was mapping... More accurately, then, "TD" stands for "table data" (the "T" stands for "Table" and the "D" stands for "Data").